# Fill out blank rows within a column in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

We currently have made a column called Change with 0 at certain rows, indicating the change of a new manager within a firm .

| Firm | Manager | Quarter | Change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 31.12.2018 |  |
| 1 | 1 | 31.03.2019 |  |
| 1 | 1 | 30.06.2019 |  |
| 1 | 1 | 30.09.2019 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 31.12.2019 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 31.03.2020 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 30.06.2020 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 30.09.2020 |  |

Is there some type of function in R that can fill out the blank rows, as depicted in the table below? The length of how long the different manager works within a certain firm varies.

| Firm | Manager | Quarter | Eventdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 31.12.2018 | -4 |
| 1 | 1 | 31.03.2019 | -3 |
| 1 | 1 | 30.06.2019 | -2 |
| 1 | 1 | 30.09.2019 | -1 |
| 1 | 2 | 31.12.2019 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 31.03.2020 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 30.06.2020 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 30.09.2020 | 3 |

Apologies for the poor explanation. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: You seem to say there are multiple 0s in the `Change` column. What do you do when the `Eventdate` values "collide" inbetween 0s? Is there guaranteed to be only one 0 in a particular firm? Or is there some other way to determine whether we get, say `0, 1, 2, -1, 0` or `0, 1, -2, -1, 0` or `0, 1, 2, 3, 0`, etc.?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, all 0s are nested within a firm.

Comment: This case mentioned above is only in the case if a firm has one manager employed at a time. This however only represents a subsample of our dataset. Note that we also have available a startdate and an enddate for each manager, respectively.

Another subsample has firms with a team of managers. These managers can have different start- and enddates, so in that case then the Eventdate-values would indeed overlap. This is something we do not have a solution for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table`  approach using a rolling join.. It seems to work fine on the sample data provided. `change2` is the column you are looking for.

```
library( data.table )
DT <- fread("Firm   Manager     Quarter     Change
1   1   31.12.2018  
1   1   31.03.2019  
1   1   30.06.2019  
1   1   30.09.2019  
1   2   31.12.2019  0
1   2   31.03.2020  
1   2   30.06.2020  
1   2   30.09.2020  ")

#add id column
DT[, id := .I ]
#set key to join on
setkey( DT, id )
#perform rolling join to nearest Change == 0, get id and subtract
DT[, change2 := id - DT[Change == 0, ][DT, x.id, roll = "nearest" ] ]

#    Firm Manager    Quarter Change id change2
# 1:    1       1 31.12.2018     NA  1      -4
# 2:    1       1 31.03.2019     NA  2      -3
# 3:    1       1 30.06.2019     NA  3      -2
# 4:    1       1 30.09.2019     NA  4      -1
# 5:    1       2 31.12.2019      0  5       0
# 6:    1       2 31.03.2020     NA  6       1
# 7:    1       2 30.06.2020     NA  7       2
# 8:    1       2 30.09.2020     NA  8       3
```

I left in the temporary columns, so you can see what is going on here.

Comment: Thank you very much, both of you! This one worked.

Answer (score 1):

Using Wimpel's nicely copy/pasteable sample data, here are `dplyr` and `data.table` solutions based on subtracting row numbers by group. It should work when there is a single row where `Change` is 0 per `Firm`.

```
DT[, Eventdate := .I - which(Change == 0), by = .(Firm)]
DT
#    Firm Manager    Quarter Change Eventdate
# 1:    1       1 31.12.2018     NA        -4
# 2:    1       1 31.03.2019     NA        -3
# 3:    1       1 30.06.2019     NA        -2
# 4:    1       1 30.09.2019     NA        -1
# 5:    1       2 31.12.2019      0         0
# 6:    1       2 31.03.2020     NA         1
# 7:    1       2 30.06.2020     NA         2
# 8:    1       2 30.09.2020     NA         3

library(dplyr)
DT %>% group_by(Firm) %>%
  mutate(Eventdate = row_number() - which(Change == 0))
# # A tibble: 8 x 5
# # Groups:   Firm [1]
#    Firm Manager Quarter    Change Eventdate
#   <int>   <int> <chr>       <int>     <int>
# 1     1       1 31.12.2018     NA        -4
# 2     1       1 31.03.2019     NA        -3
# 3     1       1 30.06.2019     NA        -2
# 4     1       1 30.09.2019     NA        -1
# 5     1       2 31.12.2019      0         0
# 6     1       2 31.03.2020     NA         1
# 7     1       2 30.06.2020     NA         2
# 8     1       2 30.09.2020     NA         3
```