# Is there a way to control for multiple treatments on the same group in an eventstudy?

Tags: r, ggplot2

We are studying changes in firm returns as an effect of changing the manager of the firm. So far, we have compiled a data table that looks like this:

| Firm | Manager | Month | Eventwindow | Return |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2015-05-31 | -3 | 83.1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2015-06-30 | -2 | 82.5 |
| 1 | 1 | 2015-07-31 | -1 | 82.7 |
| 1 | 2 | 2015-08-31 | 0 | 81.4 |
| 1 | 2 | 2015-09-30 | 1 | 78.0 |
| 1 | 2 | 2015-10-31 | 2 | 75.2 |
| 1 | 2 | 2015-11-30 | 3 | 75.1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2015-12-31 | -3 | 74.3 |
| 1 | 2 | 2016-01-31 | -2 | 78.2 |
| 1 | 2 | 2016-02-29 | -1 | 69.4 |
| 1 | 3 | 2016-03-31 | 0 | 63.1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2016-04-30 | 1 | 62.3 |
| 1 | 3 | 2016-05-31 | 2 | 60.5 |
| 1 | 3 | 2016-06-30 | 3 | 46.7 |
| 1 | 3 | 2016-07-31 | -3 | 43.9 |
| 1 | 3 | 2016-08-31 | -2 | 39.2 |
| 1 | 3 | 2016-09-30 | -1 | 38.4 |
| 1 | 4 | 2016-10-31 | 0 | 35.6 |
| 1 | 4 | 2016-11-30 | 1 | 31.8 |
| 1 | 4 | 2016-12-31 | 2 | 40.0 |
| 1 | 4 | 2017-01-31 | 3 | 44.1 |

With very good help from Gregor Thomas and Wimpel in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66819322/fill-out-blank-rows-within-a-column-in-r?noredirect=1#comment118115320_66819322) thread we used this code to achieve the aforementioned data table:

```
DT <- fread("Firm      Manager      Month      Eventdate      Change
  
  1          1       2015-05-31                   
  1          1       2015-06-30                                 
  1          1       2015-07-31                   
  1          2       2015-08-31       0            
  1          2       2015-09-30                    
  1          2   (...) "
```

#add id column

```
DT <- DT[, id := .I ]
```

#set key to join on

```
setkey(DT, id)
```

#perform rolling join to nearest Change == 0, get id and subtract

```
DT <- DT[, change2 := id - DT[Eventdate == 0, ] [DT, x.id, roll = "nearest"]]
```

, where `change2` is the column with a rolling join.

From the first table you might see that we have multiple treatment dates, i.e. `Eventwindow` = 0 at multiple points in time, for the same firm. Thus, when we plot the returns we have e.g. both 83.1, 74.9, and 43.9 as observations for "-3", and so on.

Is it possible to somehow separate these three effects from each other when running a ggplot? So far, we have used the following code to plot, but it seems that as there are numerous "duplicates" of each eventdate, both within and between firms, only a pretty flat line is returned.  When using "facet_wrap = (~Firm), the returns vary a lot more.

```
frame <- data.frame(DT$change2, DT$Return)

as.numeric(frame$DT.Active_Share)

final <- ggplot(data = frame) + 
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = DT$change2, 
                            y = DT$Return)) + 
  ylab("Return") + 
  xlab("Time") + 
  xlim(-12, 12) +
  ylim(-100.0000, 100.00000) + 
  ggtitle("Return before and after change")


final
```

EDIT1:
As requested, here's some reproducable data:

```
structure(list(Group_Investment = c("Firm 1", "Firm 1", 
"Firm 1", "Firm 1", "Firm 1", "Firm 1"
), 

ISIN = c("NO123", "NO123", "NO123", "NO123", 
"NO123", "NO123"), FundId = c("FS321", "FS321", 
"FS321", "FS321", "FS321", "FS321"), 

SecId = c("FS231", 
"FS231", "FS231", "FS231", "FS231", "FS231"
), 

ManagerName = c("John Doe", "John Doe", "John Doe", 
"Don Joe", "Don Joe", "Don Joe"), 

change2 = -3:2, 
    

Month = structure(c(16586, 16616, 16647, 16678, 16708, 
    16739), class = c("IDate", "Date")), 

Return = c(83.10196, 
    80.62931, 80.36999, 73.73783, 75.22196, 73.36678), 

Manager_Status = c("sole_manager", 
    "sole_manager", "sole_manager", "sole_manager", "sole_manager", 
    "sole_manager")), 

.internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001b14db01ef0>, row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Any help is welcome, as we are very new at using R.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. If you could make your question reproducible by pasting a sample of your data: use `dput(head(your_data_sample, n))` where `n` is enough data to demonstrate the problem this would make it easier for others to test and verify solutions.

Comment: @Peter Thank you! I have added what I hope is a reproducible sample of the data in an edit now.